# How to minimize code duplication with kobjects having the same attributes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

I have one `kobject`, say `kobj1` (so a directory in my `sysfs`) and i need to have other two `kobject`s (say `kobj2` and `kobj3`) having `kobj1` as parent. `kobj2` and `kobj3` have the same attributes so the directories structure is the same in `sysfs`. What is the best way to minimize code duplication?